# Apostrophe cms: do not want to render image title

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am using apostrophe-images to insert an image in my page.
When this widget is rendered, there is an header h4 with the title. 
I would like to remove it.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done this in the past with CSS:

```
.apos-slideshow h4 { display: none; }
```

However, you could extend the images widget and in the new template, extend the `widget.html` extend:

```
{% extends 'widgetBase.html' %}
```

and then override the title block, putting in a conditional (I think this ought to be in the base one actually!):

```
{%- block title -%}{% if data.widget.hideTitle %}<h4>{{ image.title }}</h4>{% endif %}{%- endblock -%}
```

This will then let you specify in the your new widget to hide it, ie:

```
{{ apos.singleton(data.page, 'logoHeader', 'apostrophe-images', {
        limit: 1,
        minSize: [ 100, 100 ],
        addLabel: 'Set header logo',
        editLabel: 'Change header logo',
        hideTitle: true,
        controls: {
          movable: false,
          removable: false,
          position: 'bottom-right'
        }
      }) 
}}
```

... of course, the css way is quicker!

- maybe someone else knows a better way of doing this.

Comment: Extending your own widget template is recommended for project-level changes to stock modules.

Comment: The last approach does not seem to work. Appearently there is no `data.widget.hideTitle`.
The given example might work because it is logical false: "If data.widget.hideTitle is <set>, render <title>."

Comment: the correct variable would be `data.options.hideTitle`, so the correct block would be 
`{%- block title -%}{%- if data.options.hideTitle -%}{%- else -%}<h4>{{ image.title }}</h4>{%- endif -%}{%- endblock -%}`. (Be sure to use `%-` syntax to omit unnecessary whitespaces and linefeeds)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem where I wanted to hide the image title in some modules, but style it differently in others.

There's now a class, `.apos-image-widget-image-title`, applied to the apostrophe-images h4 that you can use to style the title as you wish.

It is also possible to override the apostrophe-images template as mentioned in @bionara's answer, and I guess this is the way to go if you want to make site-wide changes to all image widgets.